# Nginx настройка 2 доменов под разными версиями php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, config

Задача состоит в том, что нужно поднять 2 домена на **Nginx**. Из которых один должен работать под **php5**, а другой - под **php7**.

---

**Server - Ubuntu**
На сервере устанавил php5 и php7.
Домены поднял, домен с php7 прекрасно работает, а домен под php5 выводит ошибку:

> 502 Bad Gateway

Думаю проблема в `include` библиотеки nginx, но решить проблему не могу.

Вывожу конфиг 2-го домена на php5.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name test.am;

#       access_log /var/log/nginx/shopinamerica.access_log main;
#       error_log /var/log/nginx/shopinamerica.error_log info;

        root /var/www/test; # директория имеется
        index index.php; # файл имеется


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # имеется
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # имеется
        }
}
```

Конфиг проверяю, не каких ошибок, но не работает.

Вот еще и  fastcgi_params:

```
    File: /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https if_not_empty;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

Буду очень благодарен за подсказку. 
Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: А /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params показать чего не хотите?

Comment: Поправил и добавил.

Comment: про сокет-файл вы написали, что он «присутствует». а кто его слушает? у вас должно быть запущено два демона *fpm*, по одному для каждой версии php.

Comment: А как запустить второй ?

Comment: @AlexMixayelovichSokolov: а первый как запускали? Аналогичным образом. Что-то вроде `service php5-fpm start`. У вас вообще php5-fpm установлен?

Comment: @МАН69К спасибо. Вопрос был решен.  service php5-fpm start ныл в статусе  stop